# Float text around div/img

Tags: html, css

I need help creating a text container floating around the price tag like seen on this [image: [picture]].

Here is what I've tried so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/kzmndzj4

```
<div class="product">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
<div class="pricetag">
    999 €
</div>
</div>
```

Problems:
I want the price tag be always on a certain position (so it's on the same position for each product) and the text floating around like on the picture I posted.

Comment: welcome, you've asked the question again...

Comment: Ok, seems like he edited the previous question, better now @user3307515

Comment: Do I have to close this question? If yes, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/Tushar490/yj2zcwjb/1/

CSS

```
body {
background-color: grey;
}
.product {
width: 258px;
height: 150px;
background-color: white;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 25px;
color: black;
padding: 5px;
position: relative;
word-break: break-all;
}
.product p {
padding: 5px;
}
.pricetag {
height: 54px;
width: 115px;
background: url('http://i.imgur.com/ES3wymx.png') no-repeat;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-left: 5px;
font-weight: bold;
top: 40%;
left: 62.2%;
position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code it may be helpful for your problem.

[Live Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kalusingh/kzmndzj4/1/)

HTML Code:

```
 <div class="product">
  <div class="pricetagspacer"></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
    <div class="pricetag">
        999 €
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="product">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
        <div class="pricetag">
            999 €
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS Code:

```
    body
{
    background-color: grey;
}
.pricetagspacer
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: -65px;
}

.product
{
    width: 258px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 25px;
    color: black;
    padding: 5px;
}

.product p
{
    padding: 5px;
}

.pricetag
{
    height: 54px;
    width: 115px;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/ES3wymx.png') no-repeat;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top:-50px;
    margin-right:-25px;
}
```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: And if the text keeps going, it goes over the price label, which is not what the OP wants. He wants it to wrap completely around the orange label.

Comment: Ok. I will modify soon.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but the text has to go around the orange tag like mentioned by Lee.

Comment: I will post full complete solution soon.